# Trying to understand how Rails testing works and having trouble with a model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, testing

Using https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html to learn how to develop automated tests.  I ran rails db:test:prepare then edited the default `./test/model/user_test.rb` (I have a users model).  This test appears very simple but I get the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: Field 'screen_name' doesn't have a default value

This should be true as I requested the field not be Null and I don't want a default value.  I want a value entered.  The database schema is set up this way.

No matter what I do I get this error.  I tried running the default controller test and its gets the same error.

I was hopping to deduce what this test is really doing as there is no real description.  Maybe this is not a valid test just some scaffolding?

A test to get a failure for not entering a value is certainly a test I need eventually.  It seems I'm not getting the instruction I need from this guide, is there a better place to start.

I tried the following:

```
@User = users.new
@User.screen_name = "Name"
...
@User.save
```

got the same result, it seems that just running a test against this model tries to create a null table entry before I do anything.  Is that true? If so how do I deal with it and not provide any defaults.

The default controller test gets the exact same result.

./test/model/user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "the truth" do
     assert true
   end
end
```

MySQL Table Desc:

```
mysql> desc users;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+--------------
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+--------------
| id              | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| screen_name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password_digest | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+--------------
```

I did not know what to expect but I did not expect what I got. Over the years I have learned start with the default and build up.

Running via Spring preloader in process 15156
Run options: --seed 50091

## Running:

> Error: UserTest#test_the_truth: Mysql2::Error: Field 'screen_name'
>   doesn't have a default value
>        bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:4
>   Finished in 0.006803s, 146.9987 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s. 1 runs, 0
>   assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared null false condition on the `User` table. Rails loads all fixtures before running each test, so when the fixture `test/fixtures/users.yml` is ran, Rails raises an error because the fixture does not have the values required by your database.

The way to solve this is to either remove the fixture: `test/fixtures/users.yml` or add the correct, necessary, values inside the fixture.

Fixtures are autogenerated when following along with that guide. That's how I know your have one for users.

It probably looks like:

```
user:
  id: 1
  screen_name: Spongebob Squarepants # this might be missing!
  email: squidwards_bestie@thebottomofthesea.com
```

Comment: That makes total sense.  I do have the fixture file but have not messed with it yet.  I want to thank you for really addressing my question.  I felt like actions were occurring on my database when not requested and wanted to know why.  By having a fixture sounds like Rails is trying to use it.  I will first remove the fixture and see if that fixes the problem.  I have high confidence it will, then add the fixture back with data.  As soon as I verify I will report my results back.  Again thanks for the response.

Comment: Renaming the users.yml to users.yml.sav worked perfectly.  Thank you so much, I have found that Rails installs stubs some of which are beneficial and some are not in situations like mine.  I must admit I used a tutorial with it's own data but injected my data which caused the problem.  On the other hand that reveled something I needed to know about testing and database schemas.

Comment: That's they key. Rails is all about being a very *opinionated* framework. If you learn Rails, you become a fast developer because you can go from idea to MVP quickly. But with configuration comes files. Lots of files. And you'll need to learn why each one exists eventually. It took me a long time before I finally just started reading the docs. Now I'd say I know about 60%-70% of Rails. But it can be a hassle sometimes and I have a ways to go. Though it may seem frustrating now, it will feel freeing if you go to an unopinionated framework which requires you doing all the custom configurations.

Comment: Thanks again I am on my way again.  I have been going through the docs as I learn.  But sometimes a question has to be asked to get a key piece of info that is missing.  You provided the missing piece I needed.  I am finding Rails very interesting and opinionated in a good way.  Look forward to learning much more.